# How can i Return Dictionary<string,string> values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dictionary, datareader

## The Query class return should return Dictionary to be retrived in the main class

```
        class Query
        {
            public Dictionary<string, string> RunQueryWithParameters(string sim_input,string CommandTxt, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
            {

                        OracleDataReader reader = cursCmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if(reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                ods_columns.Add("mob_no", reader.GetString(0));                        
                                ods_columns.Add("card_no", reader.GetString(1));
                                ods_columns.Add("account", reader.GetString(2));
                                ods_columns.Add("name", reader.GetString(3));
                                reader.NextResult();
                            }
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        reader.Close();
                        reader.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        Console.ReadLine();                  
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }
                return columns;
            }        
        }
```

## I tried to call  *RunQueryWithParameters* in The main class function

but return no value..please help#

```
   static void main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> result=new Dictionary<string,string>;
        sting input="test";
        Query test=new Query();
        Query.RunQueryWithParameters(input,string "GET_DOC_DATA", result);
        console.writeline(result["mob_no"]);
        console.writeline(result["card_no"]);
        console.writeline(result["account"]);
        console.writeline(result["name"]);
    }
```

Comment: What's 'ods_columns'? Why return 'columns' instead?

Comment: I changed the ods_columns to columns . but forget to change in ralcle reader ... anyway the error not here .. i'm asking to call ods_columns.Add("mob_no", reader.GetString(0)); in the main method

Comment: In main method you are not capturing returned values from the method to anything. How are you expecting the result have the expected output?

Comment: And where is put that instruction? Is there some other code we should see?

Comment: yup,i hide the connection string and parmaters .. and changed the variable names

Comment: How to capture the return values .?

Comment: i create dictionary<>result to capture the ods-columns

Comment: Result and ods_columns are two different variables how do you expect them to pass value to each other? You are passing result as parameter to the method but not using it at all.

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: Remove last parameter from the method and capture return value from method as `result = Query.RunQueryWithParameters(input,string "GET_DOC_DATA");`

Comment: After i remove the last parmater how can acess variable value ods_columns["mob_no"]. .... in the main class
should post all code again ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ToDictionary` method directly.

```
var result = 
  // as Jon Skeet pointed out, OrderBy is useless here, I just leave it 
  // show how to use OrderBy in a LINQ query
  myClassCollection.OrderBy(mc => mc.SomePropToSortOn)
                   .ToDictionary(mc => mc.KeyProp.ToString(), 
                                 mc => mc.ValueProp.ToString(), 
                                 StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```